# Why is wp_editor in Wordpress passing line breaks as "\n" not as "<br>" or "<p>"?

Tags: wordpress, tinymce

I'm writing a plugin that uses its own database tables (created and managed with `dbDelta` and `wpdb`). One of the fields is a rich-text area field. I am using wp_editor to create it. I create the following:

1. Hit "bold" and type "First Line"
2. Hit return (to move to next line) and type "Second line"

This appears correctly inside the textarea *(it's correct after I type it, it's incorrect when I reload after saving)*. However, when I save it, it shows in the database as:

**ACTUAL RESULTS**

```
<strong>First Line</strong>

Second Line
```

But it **should** be:

**EXPECTED RESULTS**

```
<strong>First Line</strong><br>Second Line
```

Why is it doing this? How do I make it pass my code line breaks as HTML line breaks?

I instantiate it like this:

```
wp_editor( $myContent, "myField", array( "media_buttons" => false, "textarea_rows" => 5, "quicktags" => false ) );
```

Comment: `<p>` is NOT a linebreak

Comment: @RUJordan What is your meaning? When I hit "enter" and type something on a second line, I expect the generated code from `wp_editor` to either have them wrapped in `<p>` or preceeded by a `<br>`. Neither happened. Instead it mixed HTML code with plain-text line breaks. Why the mixture?

Answer (score 0):

**This is default behavior.**

`p` and `br` tags are not added to the editor. They are used with the visual editor (for display), but when you save or switch to text, they are replaced with regular line breaks.

Single line breaks become a `br`, double line breaks will start a `p`.

Linebreak to element conversion is done when the content is displayed, using `the_content` filter (more specifically, with `wpautop`).

Comment: please reread my post. the problem is the inconsistency of single line breaks becoming `br` or \n.

Comment: You could try changing the `wpautop` option for `wp_editor`. As it stands, what you posted is normal behavior. The editor does not show br or p tags...

Comment: Actually, I don't think disabling wpautop will switch to showing the HTML tags. I don't think WordPress has a way to do this by default. You might try a plugin like this one though: http://wordpress.org/plugins/ps-disable-auto-formatting/